# Using getCountFromServer in an Atomic Transaction with Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am interested in calling "getCountFromServer" in an atomic transaction so that some writes would only apply if the getCountFromServer is not changed.

I understand getCountFromServer can't receive live updates which leads me to think this might not be possible to do yet I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

In case this isn't possible I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve similar behaviour.

Currently, I have something among these lines, yet I am almost certain it isn't properly "performing the transaction" atomically.

```
const collectionReference = collection(db, 'sales');
const q = query(collectionReference, where("storeId", "===",  storeId));

await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
  const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(q);
  const currentAmount = snapshot.data().count;
  // Some checks based on the "size of the collection" and then some writes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I am interested in calling "getCountFromServer" in an atomic transaction so that some writes would only apply if the getCountFromServer is not changed.

The transactions are by default atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied. Calling `getCountFromServer` in a transaction doesn't guarantee that the count isn't changed in the meantime. It just uses the count by the time you call the function.

> I understand getCountFromServer can't receive live updates which leads me to think this might not be possible to do yet I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Yes, counting the number of documents, is performed only once. There is currently no way you can have a real-time listener on a count unless you [create your own mechanism](https://medium.com/p/3bd0c719978f).

> Currently I have something among these lines, yet I am almost certain it isn't properly "performing the transaction" atomically.

The transaction itself is an atomic operation. So you don't have to worry about that. But remember, atomic operations are referring to writes/updates and not to read operations.

Comment: Hey Arthur. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?